# Keystone wallet hardware simulator

Tags: cryptocurrency, hardware-wallet

I need to test a binding feature between my wallet and a keystone wallet. Is there any simulator/sample that I can use to test the QR code binding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ethereum testnet blockchain to test your wallets. There are a variety of faucets that provide free test ether.
For keystone, you can use their Ropsten faucet.

Comment: My feature is about connecting the hardware wallet (keystone) to devices and making transaction. I need to know the way keystone generates the QR code for binding wallet and signing transaction. Because normal QR code generated from seed/private key didn't work.